# A simple Arduino alarm is not working

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Using the alarm library, I don't get the alarm to work:

```
#include <Time.h>
#include <TimeAlarms.h>

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  while (!Serial) 
  {
    ;  
  }

  setTime(8,29,0,1,1,10); // set time to 8:29:00am Jan 1 2010
  Alarm.timerRepeat(15, Repeats);
}

void Repeats()
{
  Serial.print("alarmed timer!");
  digitalWrite(10,1);
}

void loop() 
{

}
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? Have you triple-checked your wiring? What "alarm library" are you using? Are you using a physical alarm?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are using [this library](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_TimeAlarms.html).

If you read in the help, you can see this:

> **Normal Running Usage**
>
> Alarm.delay(milliseconds); Alarms and Timers are only checks and their
>   functions called when you use this delay function. You can pass 0 for
>   minimal delay. This delay should be used instead of the normal Arduino
>   delay(), for timely processing of alarms and timers.

so in order for the alarms to be called, you have to add this:

```
void  loop(){
  Alarm.delay(1000); // wait one second between clock display
}
```

If you prefer to check the alarm faster, you can use a lower delay (e.g. 100). You can also use 0, so the function doesn't block, but it is not mandatory for your application.

By the way, I THINK (so I can be wrong) that the call to `setTime` is used just by the other functions, not by the timer. So you can omit it. Moreover you missed the pinmode statement..

In the end.. Try this code and let us know.

```
#include <Time.h>
#include <TimeAlarms.h>

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  while (!Serial) ;

  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);

  Alarm.timerRepeat(15, Repeats);
}

void Repeats()
{
  Serial.print("alarmed timer!");
  digitalWrite(10,1);
}

void loop() 
{
  Alarm.delay(500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Alarm.delay(0); this way your program won't freeze and your alarm will work...

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5419867/edit) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead